# What's the correct preposition that connects the word "expectations" with the object of expectations?

Tags: prepositions

What's the correct preposition that connects the word "expectations" with the object of expectations?

Should it be "on", "of", "for" here or what?

> Jenny has become more active and engaged this semester; however, my
>   **expectations on her** to become more fluent did not justify themselves.

Comment: @Andrew - Thank you! Do you think it's still possible to rephrase it in such a way, in which she would not "fail"? After all, it was my failure that I was expecting too much of her, not hers.

Comment: Please see my answer  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Expectations *of*" is probably the most common, but all three can be correct.

> I have high expectations **for** the business.
>
> I have high expectations **of** our success.
>
> There may be an impact of my expectations **on** the quarterly results.

I don't really like these sentences.  My own personal style is to write them differently.

> I expect much from the business.
>
> I expect we will succeed.
>
> What I expect may affect the quarterly results.

In your example, I would probably try to use *expectation of*, although there's much I'd have to change to make it work.  For example, "justify" does not mean what you seem to be trying to make it mean.  It usually means to try to defend some bad action by saying it was done for a good reason.  Example:

> The thief tried to **justify** his theft of the bread by claiming that his family was starving, but the court was deaf to his pleas.

Instead I would say something like

> ... she did not **live up to** my expectations

or

> ... she did not **meet my** expectations

You can use either the plural *expectations* or the singular *expectation*, although the plural might be more common.  Here I prefer the singular, since you state specifically the one thing you *expected*.

> ... however, she failed to live up to my expectation **that she would become more fluent.**

If you want to be clear that it was your *expectation* that is at fault, and not her own failure, then perhaps:

> ... however, my expectation that she would become more fluent **was not met**.

or better:

> ... however I think I had **too high an expectation** that she would become more fluent.

Again, I would write this using the verb:

> ... however it seems I **expected too much from her** as she did not become more fluent.